# Three phase sine wave inverter using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to design three phase sine wave inverter using Arduino I found this link with circuit diagram and simulation results but he did not provide code. can anyone help me with code http://microcontrollerslab.com/three-phase-sine-wave-inverter/

Comment: The author explains the design of the code in http://microcontrollerslab.com/spwm-generation-using-pic16f877a-microcontroller/

Comment: It's a pretty cool article-Bilal Malik varies the duty cycle of a 20kHz PWM with a look-up table to produce 50 PWM cycles of a rising quarter-sine-wave, 50 cycles back down, then switches the polarity and does it again, using it to drive an H-bridge feeding a transformer.

Comment: This guy is doing the same. His code is free of charge. http://www.eprojectszone.com/how-to-generate-three-phase-spwm-signal-with-arduino/

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the page you are linking to, there is this notice:
"Code for three phase inverter is not free of cost. If you want to purchase code, you can contact me at bilalmalikuet@gmail.com"

If you are Bilal Malik, you should already have the code since you are offering to sell it - unless you want someone here to write it for free so you can sell it afterward.

If you are NOT Bilal Malik, you should not impersonate someone else here.

I am not a huge fan of the concept of intellectual property, but it seems you are trying to do something shady here.

Comment: It is a Roger Finer who asked the question. Why do you think he could be Bilal Malik?

Comment: @PimV: When you change your name in your stackexchange account, all your previous posts suddenly show your new name. So it is possible for a question to be asked by "a", and then show it was asked by "b".